# Inserting counter in beamer class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, sectioning, numbering

I want to create my own `beamer theme` and I've got the rough code for it.

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext,enumerate,charter}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
%\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{226, 245, 13}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{253,111,1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[inner color=blau] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \node[opacity=.6] at ([xshift=.05cm,yshift=1.03cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[red] at ([yshift=1cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[ora] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{it}Der Autor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                \node[yshift=.2cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.75cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
            \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
            \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
            \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}1};
            \draw[red,thick,yshift=.1cm] (-1,3) -- (7.7,3) node[near end,above,xshift=1cm,red] {\changefont{put}{m}{n}Der Titel};
%           \node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\color{black!85}\footnotesize\blindtext[1]}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
                \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                    \node[yshift=.26cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.6cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east)  {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
                \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
                \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
                \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}2};
                %\node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{
            \begin{enumerate}[\tikz{\fill[white]circle(.13);\fill[red]circle(.1);}]
                \item \color{black!85}Hallo,
                \item Welt!
            \end{enumerate}
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can I achieve that

- Instead of manually entering the `section` number there appears the "normal" number?

I know just some commands which changed this into a "theme", but I'm not experienced with the use of the `beamer` class, I just know the basics.

---

Here is a `MWE` of the "section-problem" (especially for [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)).

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext,enumerate,charter,comment}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
%\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{226, 245, 13}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{253,111,1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[inner color=blau] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \node[opacity=.6] at ([xshift=.05cm,yshift=1.03cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[red] at ([yshift=1cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[ora] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{it}Der Autor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}


    \section{}


    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                \node[yshift=.2cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.75cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
            \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
            \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
            \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}\thesection};
            \draw[red,thick,yshift=.1cm] (-1,3) -- (7.7,3) node[near end,above,xshift=1cm,red] {\changefont{put}{m}{n}Der Titel};
%           \node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\color{black!85}\footnotesize\blindtext[1]}
    \end{frame}


%   \section{}

\begin{comment}
    It only works when:
     - The first and the second section are uncommented and 
     - only the second section is commented.
    When only the first section is uncommented it doesn't work!
    Of course I can put just empty sections but this isn't an elegant solution …
\end{comment}

    \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
                \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                    \node[yshift=.26cm,above left] (a) at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.6cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east)  {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
                \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
                \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
                \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}\thesection};
                %\node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{
            \begin{enumerate}[\tikz{\fill[white]circle(.13);\fill[red]circle(.1);}]
                \item \color{black!85}Hallo,
                \item Welt!
            \end{enumerate}
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the current section number via `\thesection`. To deal with frames before the first section, it might be good to test if the number is >0

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \ifnum\thesection>0
        \thesection
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I want to insert `\thesection` as a node in my `tikzpicture` it always displays 0 (or when I write one section 1, two sections number 2 and so on).

Comment: @current_user works fine in a tikzpicture. Can you make a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your problem?

Comment: I posted a MWE …

Comment: @current_user Not really minimal, is it? Other than that it compiles fine for me (besides all the warnings, but they are all addressed in the comments to your previous question)

Comment: @current_user I also don't get a 0. I compile with xelatex. Need to run now.